# Пользовательские типы данных в golang

Tags: golang

У меня есть структура,в которой содержатся компоненты типов string и int. Так же в моей структуре есть типы binFunc и intList.Мой вопрос заключается в следующем: может ли сам программист создавать свои типы данных и,если да, то как эти типы данных описать?

```
    var foldTestCases = []struct {
    name     string
    property string
    fn       binFunc
    initial  int
    list     IntList
    want     int
}{
    {
        name:     "empty list",
        property: "foldl",
        fn:       func(x, y int) int { return x * y },
        initial:  2,
        want:     2,
        list:     []int{},
    }
```

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Какой пользователь? Программист может. Пользователь — только через мутные дебри отражения.

Comment: (исправлено) Так понятнее?Если программист может,то как?

Answer (score 0):

Ваш вопрос всё ещё довольно странный, то тем не менее. Новые типы
создаются с помощью ключевого слова `type`:

```golang
type binFunc func(x, y int) (z int)

type intList []int
```

Это новые типы с новыми наборами методов. Также можно создавать синонимы
типов (англ. *type alias*):

```golang
type binFunc = func(x, y int) (z int)

type intList = []int
```

Это просто второе название того же типа.